# Acortar un código en Java

Tags: java, bucle-for, print, switch

hice un código que imprime resistencias (en forma de texto) y calcula su valor. Esto es lo que pidió mi profesor de la universidad (Aclaro nuevamente que soy nuevo en Java)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según djo mi profesor, que se puede hacer un código para este ejercicio con unas 40-50 líneas de código, en base a los conocimientos de polimorfismo y sobrecarga. En el caso de mi código, estoy ocupando 90 líneas de código.
Sinceramente aún no puedo manejar bien los conceptos de polimorfismo y sobrecarga y por falta de práctica, no me salen como desearía. Aquí mi código, espero que se puedan reducir las líneas de código, he pensado que tiene que ver con el switch, pero espero que puedan ayudarme. Por favor:

```
public class Resistencias{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String band1 =" ", band2 = " ", band3 = " ", band4 = " ";
    String n1 = " ", n2=" ", n3 =" ", n4 =" ";
    int color1 = 0, color2 = 0, color3 = 0, color4 = 0;
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int x = 1; x <=10; x++) { //Para cada resistencia
        System.out.println("\n"+"--------------------------"+"\n\033[35mResistance: "+x+"\033[0m"); //Separador por cada resistencia
             color1 = r.nextInt(11)+1; color2 = r.nextInt(11)+1; color3 = r.nextInt(11)+1; color4 = r.nextInt(6)+1; //Generar el número que indicará el color de la banda de la resistencia (4 bandas por resistencia)
            switch(color1) { //1er Banda, 
                case 1: band1 = ("black-->0"); n1="0";
                break;
                case 2: band1 = ("brown-->1"); n1="1";  
                break;
                case 3: band1 = ("red-->2"); n1="2";
                break;
                case 4: band1 = ("orange-->3"); n1="3";
                break;
                case 5: band1 = ("yellow-->4"); n1="4";
                break;
                case 6: band1 = ("green-->5"); n1="5";
                break;
                case 7: band1 = ("blue-->6"); n1="6";
                break;
                case 8: band1 = ("purple-->7"); n1="7";
                break;
                case 9: band1 = ("gray-->8"); n1="8";
                break;
                case 10: band1 = ("white-->9"); n1="9";
                break; 
            }
            switch(color2) { //2da Banda
                case 1: band2 = ("black-->0"); n2="0";
                break;
                case 2: band2 = ("brown-->1"); n2="1";
                break;
                case 3: band2 = ("red-->2"); n2="2";
                break;
                case 4: band2 = ("orange-->3"); n2="3";
                break;
                case 5: band2 = ("yellow-->4"); n2="4";
                break;
                case 6: band2 = ("green-->5"); n2="5";
                break;
                case 7: band2 = ("blue-->5"); n2="6";
                break;
                case 8: band2 = ("purple-->7"); n2="7";
                break;
                case 9: band2 = ("gray-->8"); n2="8";
                break;
                case 10: band2 = ("white-->9"); n2="9";
                break; 
            }
            switch(color3) { //3ra Banda
                case 1: band3 = ("black--> x1"); n3="";
                break;
                case 2: band3 = ("brown-->0"); n3="0";
                break;
                case 3: band3 = ("red-->00"); n3="00";
                break;
                case 4: band3 = ("orange-->000"); n3=",000";
                break;
                case 5: band3 = ("yellow-->0000"); n3="0,000";
                break;
                case 6: band3 = ("green-->00000"); n3="00,000";
                break;
                case 7: band3 = ("blue-->000000"); n3=",000,000";
                break;
                case 8: band3 = ("purple-->0000000"); n3="0,000,000";
                break;
                case 9: band3 = ("gray-->00000000"); n3="00,000,000";
                break;
                case 10: band3 = ("white-->000000000"); n3=",000,000,000";
                break; 
            }
            switch(color4) { //4ta Banda
                case 1: band4 = ("brown-->1%"); n4=" \u00B1 1% \u2126";
                break;
                case 2: band4 = ("red-->2%"); n4=" \u00B1 2% \u2126";
                break;
                case 3: band4 = ("green-->0.5%"); n4=" \u00B1 0.5% \u2126";
                break;
                case 4: band4 = ("gold-->5%"); n4=" \u00B1 5% \u2126";
                break;
                case 5: band4 = ("silver-->10%"); n4=" \u00B1 10% \u2126";
                break;
            }
         System.out.println("Band1:    "+band1+"\nBand2:    "+band2+"\nBand3:    "+band3+"\nBand4:    "+band4+"\n \033[36mResistance is = \033[31m"+n1+n2+n3+n4+"\033[33m");
    }//Ciclo for x
}//Fin de la clase
```

Comment: NO hay forma de aplicar polimorfismo sobre tu código actual, pues no tienes más que una clase `Resistencias`. Polimorfismo solo existe si creas una jerarquía de clases, por ejemplo una clase `Banda`, que representa una banda genérica, y de esa derivas (especializas) varias clases de bandas, por ejemplo `BandaTolerancia`, `BandaCeros` (por decir algo). Finalmente, tu clase `Resistencia` es una composición de 4 bandas, donde cada banda sabe imprimir su color y su valor, por ejemplo.

Comment: De hecho puede salir en unas 15 líneas. Pon los colores incluyendo los de tolerancias en un arreglo, que la posición (índice) sea el valor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrego código refactorizado. Algunos comentarios de referencia están adentro.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Resistencias{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int color1;
    int color2;
    int color3;
    int color4;
    
    // las bandas 1, 2 solo usan colores del 0 - 9
    // el multiplicador usa del 0 - 11
    String[] coloresBanda = new String[]{"negro","marron","rojo","naranja","amarillo","verde","azul","violeta","gris","blanco","oro","plata"};
    String[] coloresTolerancia = new String[]{"marron","rojo","verde","azul","violeta","gris","oro","plata"};
    double[] multiplicadores = new double[] {1, 10 , 100, 1000, 10_000, 100_000, 1_000_000, 10_000_000, 100_000_000, 1_000_000_000, 0.1, 0.01};
    String[] tolerancias = new String[]{"1", "2", "0.5", "0.25", "0.1", "0.05", "5", "10"};
    
    Random r = new Random();
  
    for (int x = 1; x <=10; x++) { 
        System.out.println("\n"+"--------------------------"+"\nResistance: " + x); 
        
             color1 = r.nextInt(10);  //  random entre 0 - 9, el 10 no se incluye
             color2 = r.nextInt(10);
             color3 = r.nextInt(12);  //  random entre 0 y 11, el 12 no se incluye
             color4 = r.nextInt(8);  //   random entre 0 y 7, el 8 no se incluye
           
    
        System.out.println("Color 1: " + coloresBanda[color1] + ", Color 2: " + coloresBanda[color2] + ", Color 3: " + coloresBanda[3] + ", Color 4: " +coloresBanda[color4]);
        double multiplicacion = Integer.parseInt(color1 + "" + color2)* multiplicadores[color3];
        System.out.println("Valores: " + color1 + " " + color2 + " " +  color3 + " = " + multiplicacion + " al " + tolerancias[color4]);
    }
}  
}
```